# input image size for deep learinng models

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, keras

i have two set of images. One of size 120*60 and other of size 1022*81. Most of the deep learning models require size 224*224 or some other standard dimension as an input. Can i put these images directly as an input to my model and expect the accuracy close to whatever they have been trained on initially or should i try to define my own filter sizes for each layer?

Comment: See this question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48230031/712995